# Updating a single cell (not the entire row) in slickgrid with DataView

Tags: slickgrid, dataview

I have a slickgrid (using a DataView) that I'm using to display rapidly changing values.  As far as I know, when a value changes in the underlying model, the only choice I have is to update the entire row:

```
dataView.updateItem(rowId, rowData);
```

Unfortunately, even if certain values haven't changed (i.e. I'm only updating one cell's value in the entire row), slickgrid repaints the entire row (I'm using the Chrome dev tools to see what is being rendered).

I also have a < table > implementation of the same UI and here I'm able to paint individual cells (or groups of cells) that update, and rendering is roughly 3x as fast.  It's not exactly apples-to-apples, but I would like to be able to limit the amount of painting that occurs if possible, considering on any given update, generally only one or two cells (on a long row of data) have changed.

Comment: You could use SlickGrid without the DataView. That would allow you to update/invalidate/render the individual cells as you wish.

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
slickGrid.updateCell(row, cell);
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately that doesn't work when using a DataView.  I ended up just getting rid of the DataView (I didn't really need the add'l functionality it offered), which let me use this method.